# VS2010: assert "vector iterators incompatible" in std::vector.clear()

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, assert, assertion

I'm using following stupid code:

```
std::vector<wxString> m_redoSteps;
...
m_redoSteps.clear();
```

When I'm compiling with Visual Studio 6 or GCC m_redoSteps.clear() works fine, when I use visual Studio 2010 there is an assertion "vector iterators incompatible" (which leads to a crash in release build).

Any ideas what is wrong here?

--

Edit: Adding one more line of code:

```
std::vector<wxString> m_redoSteps;
...
if (!m_redoSteps.empty())
{
   // do something in case it is not empty - which isn't in my case
   ...
}
m_redoSteps.clear(); // first call leads to the assertion...
```

Comment: The two lines of code you have shown us are fine. So the problem is in some of the code you *haven't* shown us.

Comment: can you post code of 'do something' ?

Comment: "do something" is not interesting since is it not called when the assertion happens!

Comment: Since there are no iterators shown in the code you provided, you can probably be assured the problem is *not* here. Try again.

Comment: @Elmi: I'm sorry, if you already know what the problem is, why did you ask the question? If you **don't** know what the problem is, then you are not in a position to say whether a piece of code is relevant. So when we ask to see some code, show it to us. You might be too lazy to look at your own code, but you can't expect us to fix it without seeing the code. The problem is not in calling `m_redoSteps.clear()`. So if the error occurs on that line, some code that was executed *before* it must have brought the vector into an invalid state

Comment: What exactly is the code represented in the `...` above the `if (!m_redoSteps.empty())` ??

Comment: Most likely: You have a bug somewhere in your own code. Less likely: You found a VS2010 bug. Unfortunately, we can't tell because you havn't yet provided a reduced but complete example which exhibits this problem.

Comment: Even if your assertion of the code within the `if` block never executes is true, the code between `std::vector<wxString> m_redoSteps;` and `if (!m_redoSteps.empty())` *is* called regardless, so post it.

Comment: @jalf: the code within the brackets (the "do something" code) is not called because the vector is empty initially - so how should it have an influence to the problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I can't post several hundreds of lines of code here. On the other hand: why is it working fine with two other compilers and fails only with VS2010?

Comment: Because VS-debug iterators are paranoid about their own destruction when the content they're iterating is destroyed before they are. you know where the condition that introduces this is happening, the code in the block mentioned prior. I'm guessing there is an iterator in the same code-scope as the vector.clear() call. But since we have no code to examine, only you can know that for sure. vtc.

Comment: @Elmi: if that code is not called, then remove it from your own test code, compile it, and see if the problem still exists. Keep doing that: remove code, see if you can still reproduce the problem, and if not, add the code back. That eventually gives you a minimal code example that you can post here. What you've posted here does **not** give the error you are talking about, so the error must be in some other part of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install visual studio 2010 sp1, see this bug report : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/545013

**Update (April 14, 2015):**

The bug description is *545013: The "vector::erase" constraint returns an incompatible iterator in the debug build.*

The original link http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/545013 is not available, however a cache of the original bug is here http://web.archive.org/web/20140727031651/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/545013

The bug was resolved in Visual Studio SP 1 as described here [Description of Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983509)